# Python: Modify the internal behavior of a function by using decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I'm learning to use python decorator.

```
def my_dcrtr(fun):
    def new_fun():
        return fun()
    return new_fun
```

I realize the decorated function 'fun' acts like a black box inside the decorator. I can choose to use fun() or not at all inside new_fun. However, I don't know whether I can break into 'fun' and interact with fun's local scope inside the new_fun?

e.g. I'm trying to make a toy Remote Procedural Call (RPC) with python.

```
def return_locals_rpc_decorator(fun):
    def decorated_fun(*args, **kw):
        local_args = fun(*args, **kw)
        # pickle the local_args and send it to server
        # server unpickle and doing the RPC
        # fetch back server results and unpickle to results
        return rpc_results

    return decorated_fun


@return_locals_rpc_decorator
def rpc_fun(a, b, c=3):
    return locals() # This looks weird. how can I make this part of the decorator?


print(rpc_fun(2, 1, 6))
```

In this example, I try to get rpc_fun's argument list at runtime with the 'locals()' command. Then send it to server to execute. Instead of letting rpc_fun returns its locals(), is it possible to use the decorator to retrieve decorated function's argument space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function annotations for Python3:

```
def return_locals_rpc_decorator(fun):
   def decorated_fun(*args, **kw):
      local_args = fun(*args, **kw) 
      print(local_args)
      fun_parameters = fun.__annotations__
      final_parameters = {a:list(args)[int(b[-1])-1] for a, b in fun_parameters.items() if a != 'return'}
      return final_parameters
   return decorated_fun

@return_locals_rpc_decorator
def my_funct(a:"val1", b:"val2", c:"val3") -> int:
    return a + b + c

print(my_funct(10, 20, 30))
```

Output:

```
60
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
```

In this way, you are using the wrapper function `decorated_fun` to access the decorated function's parameters and further information specified by the annotation. I changed the parameter descriptions in the annotations so that each string value would end in a digit that could be used to index `args`. However, if you do not want to change the parameter descriptions in the annotations, you can sort via ending character.

Edit: the code in the body of `my_funct` is executed when called in the wrapper function (`decorated_fun`), since the `args`, declared in the scope of `decorated_fun` is passed to and unpacked in `local_args`.

Comment: I don't get how this work. What I need is make 'fun_parameters' inside the 'decorated_fun' equal to {'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30} at runtime, so that I can send it to the server. Is this possible?

Comment: Awesome! This perfectly solves my problem! Two remaining questions if you don't mind: 1. Everything in the body of function (i.e. a+b+c) will never be executed, right? 2. (nvm ... I made a mistake ...)

Comment: @ShichuZhu glad to help! The code in the body of the function is in fact executed, since the function is called in the wrapper function. Please see my recent edit for more information.